# Wordpress: How to get custom meta in wordpress?

Tags: php, wordpress

For every blog post I need to show the custom meta guest_author, if that is not set then default user.

This is what I want to do in PHP, please help

If guest_author is available
echo guest_author
else
echo author

Comment: please update your question with your attempt. Your question's logic is in 2nd link's last answer.   Visit this Link : 1.[/replace-author-url-with-guest-author-link](https://wordpress.org/support/topic/replace-author-url-with-guest-author-link) 2. [/how-to-handle-guest-authors-without-creating-profiles](https://wordpress.org/support/topic/how-to-handle-guest-authors-without-creating-profiles)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what I ultimately did:

```
<span class="post-info-text"><?php echo 'This interview was taken by: </span> <span class="author-name vcard fn author" itemprop="name">'; ?>
<?php $guest_author = get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), 'guest_author', true);
if (!$guest_author){the_author_posts_link();}else{echo $guest_author;} ?></span>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use something like:

```
$userID = the_author_meta( 'ID' );
if ($userID!= 0) //0 is for admin author id
   {
     get_the_author_meta( '/*what ever you want to get */' )
     }
else
{
  //The else part for the default admin author.
}
```

Reference:https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_author_meta